# Mysterious Black Dot

Tags: 3d-view

I have a black dot in my scene view (it is floating in world position) which I can't delete and I have no clue how it occured:

[image]

This dot is only visible when I have selected the armature, but I can't manipulate this black dot with any bones in any way.

I duplicated this model from my base model and saved it in another file to create seperate animations, then I noticed this black dot.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem?

Comment: Is it possible you could upload the .blend?

Comment: sure, here it is: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/78559347/Tiger2.rar

Comment: okay quick update, I have succesfully reproduced this error: I have shift + x clicked some animations in the action editor which I didn't need anymore. Hope it helps, and thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a grease pencil layer. You can delete it in the Properties Panel (press <kbd>N</kbd> in 3D View to open/close). Select the Armature and click on the "x".

[image]